# Is the verb resumes in "College resumes Monday" transitive?

Tags: verbs

I'm working through verb types at the moment, and I was wondering if one considers the days of the week as nouns or adverbs in the context of the sentence "College resumes Monday".

It wouldn't really make too much sense to say that Monday is a direct object, which leads me to believe that the verb "resumes" is intransitive. But wouldn't the correct form in this situation be: "College resumes *on* Monday"?

Comment: Obviously, you have made erroneous presumptions being distracted by the verb. Dropping the *on* is the real issue and has nothing to do with the nature of the verb *resume*, which is intransitive. You should look up the endless number of sentences (and esp. titles/ signages) that drop the *on* before the name of a week day. See photo captions in newspapers for more examples.

Comment: This not a real question, but a misunderstanding/ misinterpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. "Resumes" is intransitive in this case, and "College resumes *on* Monday" is the full form of this sentence. However, when referring to days of the week, it is pretty common practice to drop the "on".

[image: NGram comparison]

As you can see, dropping the "on" is a *bit* less common (at least in the case of resuming [on] Monday), but it is still a well-understood way to say the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The correct form would indeed be

> College resumes on Monday.

However, the preposition can sometimes be omitted, especially in news headlines. But that doesn't make *Monday* the direct object of *resume*.

The verb resume can be a transitive verb, too. For example:

> The program resumed its work.